# Updating column value with its predecessor

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Consider a test dataset

```
 test = data.table("a"=c(NA,NA, 0, NA, NA), "b"=c(1,3,4,7,8), "c"=c(NA, 2,1,3,1), "group"=c(1,1,1,1,1))
    a  b c  group
 1: NA 1 NA 1
 2: NA 3  2 1
 3:  0 4  1 1
 4: NA 7  3 1
 5:  0 8  1 1
 6: NA 9  1 1
```

I want to update the value of a column such that:

```
  t = a_{i-1}+c_i
  if(is.na(a_i)) {
    a_i = t       
  }
```

This should result in the following dataset:

```
    a  b c  group
 1: NA 1 NA 1
 2: NA 3  2 1
 3:  0 4  1 1
 4:  3 7  3 1
 5:  0 8  1 1
 6:  1 9  1 1
```

I reduced the example to one group but there can be multiple. I would prefer to avoid for loop solution because my actual dataset has millions of rows.

Comment: This is because `NA` plus anything is still `NA`. Row 4 evaluates `0 + 3 = 3` and row 5 evaluates the `NA` from row 4 (it hasn't been replaced yet) plus the 1, and produces `NA`. If you want to update *sequentially*, you can't use the `:=` or `*apply` constructions, you will have to use a `for` loop or similar.

Comment: why does `a` remain equal to 0 on row 3? why isn't everything `NA`?

Answer (score 0):

It was not clear to me what the logic is when you have a `NA` value before the first non-`NA` `a`. I presume it is to keep the current value of `a`. In that case, then this might be what you are looking forward:

```
> library(zoo)
> test = data.table("a"=c(NA,NA, 0, NA, NA, 1, 2), 
+                   "b"=c(1,3,4,7,8, 9, 10), 
+                   "c"=c(NA, 2,1,3,1, 1, 2), 
+                   "group"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1, 1))
> test
    a  b  c group
1: NA  1 NA     1
2: NA  3  2     1
3:  0  4  1     1
4: NA  7  3     1
5: NA  8  1     1
6:  1  9  1     1
7:  2 10  2     1
> 
> test[, `:=`(tmp_idx = shift(cumsum(!is.na(a)), fill = 0) > 0)][
+   , c_cum := cumsum(c), by = tmp_idx][
+     tmp_idx == 0, c_cum := 0][
+       tmp_idx == TRUE, a := NA][
+         , a := na.locf(a, na.rm = FALSE)]
> test
    a  b  c group tmp_idx c_cum
1: NA  1 NA     1   FALSE     0
2: NA  3  2     1   FALSE     0
3:  0  4  1     1   FALSE     0
4:  0  7  3     1    TRUE     3
5:  0  8  1     1    TRUE     4
6:  0  9  1     1    TRUE     5
7:  0 10  2     1    TRUE     7
> 
> test[, a := ifelse(is.na(shift(a)), a, shift(a)) + c_cum][
+   , `:=`(tmp_idx = NULL, c_cum = NULL)]
> test
    a  b  c group
1: NA  1 NA     1
2: NA  3  2     1
3:  0  4  1     1
4:  3  7  3     1
5:  4  8  1     1
6:  5  9  1     1
7:  7 10  2     1
```

If you have more groups then use the above on `.SD` inside the `[.data.table` call with a `by` argument.

Comment: There are likely smarter ways to fill in the first non-`NA` value then using the `zoo::na.locf` function as above.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for the reply. I made a mistake and did not specify what would happen if you have NA and then some additional numbers. In your case counting continues, in my example I would like to restart the counter with the value after NA. In this case your solution would not work :(